Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2}\,\mathrm{d}z$
Trying to calculate
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2}\,\mathrm{d}z $$
using contour integration.
for $t > 0$, I use the lower semicircle that encapsulates the singularity at $z = -i$.
I calculated the residue for the singularity (a pole of order 2) at $z = -i$ as $\operatorname{Res}[f, -i] = ite^t$, and so came up with overall value for the integral of $-2\pi i \operatorname{Res}[f, -i] = 2\pi te^t$ (with the minus sign coming from the fact I'm integrating clockwise on the lower half circle).
Is this correct? and if so, for $t < 0$, it seems I may need to use a different contour, perhaps a rectangular one? or another trick? Any help and/or hint appreciated.

I think you have mixed up the reasoning for $t<0$ and $t>0$. For $t<0$ you can close the contour in the LHP and get the result you got. For $t>0$ you can close the contour in the UHP and get zero.

The correct answer is
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z = \begin{cases}
0, & t \geq 0, \\[0.25em]
2\pi t e^t, & t < 0.
\end{cases} $$
So, what have gone wrong? When $t > 0$ and $\operatorname{Im}(z) < 0$, by writing $z = \sigma - i\xi$ with $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\xi > 0$ we get
$$ e^{itz} = e^{\xi t} e^{it\sigma}. $$
Note that the factor $e^{\xi t}$ grows exponentially fast as $\xi \to \infty$. This behavior is clearly seen from the following complex plot of $f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{(z+i)^2}$ (corresponding to the integrand with $t=1$):

(Here, the upright vertical axis represents the magnitude $|f(z)|$ and the color represents the argument $\arg f(z)$.)
An important implication is that the integral of $\frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2}$ along the lower semicircular is not guaranteed to vanish as the radius goes to infinity (and indeed, it does not).
Instead, let's choose the upper semicircular contour when $t > 0$. More specifically, let $\Gamma^+_R$ denote the upper semicircular contour of radius $R$ centered at the origin and oriented counter-clockwise. Then
\begin{align*}
\left| \int_{\Gamma^+_R} \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z \right|
&= \left| \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\exp(it Re^{i\theta})}{(i + Re^{i\theta})^2} \, (iRe^{i\theta}) \mathrm{d}\theta \right| \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{R \exp(-t R\sin\theta)}{(R-1)^2} \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&\leq \frac{\pi R}{(R-1)^2},
\end{align*}
showing that $\int_{\Gamma^+_R} \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z
&= \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z \\
&= \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{[-R,R]\cup\Gamma^+_R} \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

Now when $t < 0$, the function $f(z) = \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2}$ grows exponentially fast as $\operatorname{Im}(z) \to +\infty$, as we can see from the following complex plot of $f(z)$ corresponding to $t = -1$:

For this reason, we choose the lower semicircular contour $\Gamma^-_R$ oriented clockwise. A similar argument as above shows that $\int_{\Gamma^-_R} \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$, hence
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z
&= \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z \\
&= \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{[-R,R]\cup\Gamma^-_R} \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z \\
&= -2\pi i \, \underset{z=-i}{\mathrm{Res}} \, \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2} \\
&= 2\pi t e^t.
\end{align*}

beautiful, thank you for the long and thoughtful answer! I did indeed mixup the case of t>0 and t<0 and your answer adds much insight. thank you.


Trying to calculate
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2}\,\mathrm{d}z $$


...for $t > 0$, I use the lower semicircle that encapsulates the singularity at $z = -i$.


...$= 2\pi te^t$ ... Is this correct?

No, it is correct for $t < 0$, not $t>0$.
You can close the contour in the LHP only for $t < 0$, not $t > 0$. This is because you are shooting down the complex axis so your integrand is looking like $e^{it(-iy)} = e^{ty}$, and you want $t<0$ so you can have something like $e^{-|t|y}$ and close the contour.

and if so, for $t < 0$, it seems I may need to use a different contour,

For $t>0$ the answer is zero, because you just close the contour in the UHP and pick up no poles/residues. For $t<0$ the answer is $2\pi te^t$, for the reasons you already stated.

For example, with $t=1 > 0$ you have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+i)^2} = 0\;.
$$
For example, with $t=-1 < 0$ you have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-iz}}{(z+i)^2} = -\frac{2\pi}{e}\;.
$$
